# Why am I getting a blank array?

Tags: ruby

I am getting a blank array when I try to print after getting continuous input.

```
puts "Enter the numbers you want"
arr = Array.new()
while gets
  arr.each do |x|
    arr =x.to_i
  end
end
print arr, ","
```

Output:

```
Enter the numbers you want
1
2

3
^Z
[],
```

I would like to know if this is the right way to use `gets` and if there is a good source on handling continuous inputs in Ruby.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  Can you please edit your question to show what output you expect?  Also, what does "continuous input" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is empty, because you never actually add values to that array. Try this:

```
puts "Enter the numbers you want"
arr = []

while x = gets
  arr << x.to_i          # this line adds x (input from `gets`) to the array
  puts arr.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: yeah, `to_i` will be helpful here :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not populating the array. `gets` returns a string that you entered. You ignore it.

If you wanted to populate the array from user input, you should have something like this:

```
puts "Enter the numbers you want"
arr = []
while input = gets
  arr << input.chomp  # strip off trailing newline
end

p arr
```